# Print out a decimal number

Tags: assembly, x86

My code should print out a decimal number, but it won't and I don't know why.

I'm only a beginner and I already read a lot of advices, but I can't fix that. Thank for reactions! (the number to print is `COUNT`)

```
        printout proc
xor dl, dl
mov dl, OFFSET COUNT
xor bx,bx
mov bh, 0ah
mov ax,dx
div bh 
mov bh,ah 
mov bl,al
xor dx,dx
mov dl,bl 
add dx,’0′ 
mov ah,02h 
int 21h
xor dx,dx
mov dl,bh
add dx,’0′ 
mov ah,02h 
int 21h
ret
endp
```

Comment: Learn to use a debugger and single step your code. Furthermore, if you would like others to help, take time to comment your code and provide better problem description than `it won't`. See also [ask].

Answer (score 2):

To read the value of COUNT either use `mov dl,byte [COUNT]` or `mov dl,COUNT`.
It depends on the assembler you are using.

You should also use `xor dh,dh` in stead of `xor dl,dl`.

The largest number that you can correctly process is 99.

You could simplify the code.

```
xor ah, ah
mov al, COUNT
mov bh, 0ah
div bh 
mov bx,ax 
mov dl,bl 
add dl,’0′ 
mov ah,02h 
int 21h
mov dl,bh
add dl,’0′ 
mov ah,02h 
int 21h
ret
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to convert the number to string, then you can "print it out". Next code was made with EMU8086 and shows how to do it (comments will help you to understand) :

```
.stack 100h
.data

num  dw 10382      ;ANY NUMBER.
str  db 7 dup('$') ;STRING TO STORE NUMBER. 

.code          
;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
  mov  ax, @data
  mov  ds, ax

;CONVERT "NUM" TO STRING. RESULT COMES BACK IN "STR".
  mov  ax, num
  call number2string

;DISPLAY NUMBER.
  mov  ah, 9
  mov  dx, offset str ;NUMBER CONVERTED TO STRING.
  int  21h

;STOP UNTIL USER PRESS ANY KEY.
  mov  ah,7
  int  21h

;FINISH THE PROGRAM PROPERLY.
  mov  ax, 4c00h
  int  21h           

;------------------------------------------

;NUMBER TO CONVERT MUST ENTER IN AX.
;ALGORITHM : EXTRACT DIGITS ONE BY ONE, STORE
;THEM IN STACK, THEN EXTRACT THEM IN REVERSE
;ORDER TO CONSTRUCT STRING.

proc number2string
  mov  bx, 10 ;DIGITS ARE EXTRACTED DIVIDING BY 10.
  mov  cx, 0 ;COUNTER FOR EXTRACTED DIGITS.
cycle1:       
  mov  dx, 0 ;NECESSARY TO DIVIDE BY BX.
  div  bx ;DX:AX / 10 = AX:QUOTIENT DX:REMAINDER.
  push dx ;PRESERVE DIGIT EXTRACTED FOR LATER.
  inc  cx ;INCREASE COUNTER FOR EVERY DIGIT EXTRACTED.
  cmp  ax, 0  ;IF NUMBER IS
  jne  cycle1 ;NOT ZERO, LOOP. 
;NOW RETRIEVE PUSHED DIGITS.
  mov  si, offset str
cycle2:  
  pop  dx        
  add  dl, 48 ;CONVERT DIGIT TO CHARACTER.
  mov  [ si ], dl
  inc  si
  loop cycle2  

  ret
endp
```