# My code that multiplies and adds does not produce the correct result

Tags: assembly, expression, x86-16

I want to calculate this perimeter expression

```
(hight * 2) + (width * 2)
```

example:

> Enter hight: 3
> Enter width: 2
> perimeter is : 10

> Enter hight: 1
> Enter width: 1
> perimeter is : 4

```
.model small
    cr equ 0Dh
    lf equ 0Ah
.data
    msg1 db cr,lf,'Enter hight: $'
    msg2 db cr,lf,'Enter width: $'
    msg3 db cr,lf,'perimeter is : $'
.stack 100h
.code
main    proc
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax
    lea dx,msg1
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h
    mov ah,1h
    int 21h
    sub al,30h
    mov cl,2
    mul cl
    mov bx,ax
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax
    lea dx,msg2
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h
    mov ah,1h
    int 21h
    sub al,30h
    mov cl,2
    mul cl
    mov cx,ax
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax
    lea dx,msg3
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h
    add cx,bx
    mov ah,2h
    int 21h
    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h
main    endp
end main
```

My code does not give the correct result. How can I fix my code?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you are printing your result properly -  see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30139706/printing-decimal-number-in-assembly-language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> add cx,bx
> mov ah,2h
> int 21h
> ```

You have put the result in the `CX` register but the single character output function 02h expects your character in the `DL` register.

Quick fix:

```
mov dl, cl
add dl, '0'
mov ah, 02h
int 21h
```

Since this outputs a single character, you should not expect it to display the two-digit result from your first example (10)!

---

The longest perimeter (36) you get from inputting 9 twice.
Next code can output numbers in the range [0,99]:

```
  mov al, cl      ; [0,36]
  aam             ; -> AH = perimeter / 10    AL=perimeter % 10
  add ax, 3030h
  mov cx, ax
  cmp ch, "0"
  je  SkipLeadingZero
  mov dl, ch      ; tens
  mov ah, 02h
  int 21h
SkipLeadingZero:
  mov dl, cl      ; ones
  mov ah, 02h
  int 21h
```

### Some additional advice

- You don't need to reload the `DS` segment register each time you output a message
- You can re-arrange an expression so as to simplify the calculation

  ```
    (hight * 2) + (width * 2) <=> (hight + width) * 2
  ```
- Multiplication by 2 should be repaced by a single shift to the left.

  ```
    (hight + width) * 2 <=> (hight + width) << 1
  ```

Assuming *hight* is in `BL` and *width* is in `CL`:

```
mov al, bl    ; BL=[0,9]
add al, cl    ; CL=[0,9]
shl al, 1     ; -> AL=[0,36]
aam
...
```